# Индекс нажатого элемента в блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

В блоке div.divClass 
такой перечень элементов:

span
p
span
p
span
...

span - кликабельный, нужно на событие onCLick определить, какой по счету span нажат, как это сделать ?

Я пробовал через метод index(), но он учитывает не точки порядок спанов..

Answer (score 2):

ред.:
можно найти все предыдущие спаны через `prevAll()`

```js
$("span").click(function(){
  let idx = $(this).prevAll("span").length;
  console.log(idx);
});
```

```css
p { margin: 0; display: inline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>p</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>p</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>p</p>
</div>
<div>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>p</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>p</p>
  <span>span</span>
  <p>p</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно, имелся в виду индекс внутри заданного контейнера.

Comment: @Igor да, вероятно так. я почему-то решил, что привязка к родителю останется. тогда через `prevAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно каждому span в этом листе выдать пользовательский атрибут - скажем, data-span-index - и проиндексировать их там. Потом в обработчике получать индекс (`event.target.getAttribue('data-span-index')` или, средствами jq, `event.target.attr('data-span-index')`)

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так без библиотек. Поместить все span в массив, и уже по нему искать порядок элемента

```
const block = document.querySelector('.block');
const spanArr = []
for (el of block.children) {
  if (el.tagName == 'SPAN') {
    spanArr.push(el)
  }
}

block.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let idx = spanArr.findIndex( span => span === e.target)
  if (idx !== -1) {
    idx++
    alert(idx)
  }
})
```